# Optimize update and insert query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this code:

```
string query = @"UPDATE [dbo].[TrippingTariffTransaction]
                 SET [IsActive] = 0
                 WHERE Id in (SELECT Id 
                              FROM [dbo].[TrippingTariffTransaction] 
                              WHERE Trip = @Trip 
                                AND TrippingTariffId = @TrippingTariffId);";
query += @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[TrippingTariffTransactionAuditTrail]
                            (LogDatetime, MasterlistId, ComputerName, TrippingTariffTransactionID, Activity)                       
               SELECT 
                   GETDATE(), @MasterlistId, @ComputerName, Id, @Activity 
               FROM 
                   [dbo].[TrippingTariffTransaction] 
               WHERE 
                   Trip = @Trip AND TrippingTariffId = @TrippingTariffId";
```

How can I optimize this code. I have redundant select. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please tell us what **concrete database system** this is for - many things are vendor-specific. Are you using MySQL? Postgres? SQL Server? Oracle? IBM DB2? Something else entirely? Please update your tags to show what database system (and which version of it!) you're using - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `OUTPUT` clause

```
update  t
set     IsActive    = 0
OUTPUT  getdate(), @MasterlistId, @ComputerName, INSERTED.Id, @Activity
INTO    TrippingTariffTransactionAuditTrail 
        ( LogDatetime, MasterlistId, ComputerName, TrippingTariffTransactionID, Activity)
FROM    TrippingTariffTransaction t
WHERE   t.Trip             = @Trip 
AND     t.TrippingTariffId = @TrippingTariffId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `temp` table:

```
SELECT Id INTO #T
FROM [dbo].[TrippingTariffTransaction] 
WHERE Trip = @Trip 
AND TrippingTariffId = @TrippingTariffId

UPDATE [dbo].[TrippingTariffTransaction]
SET [IsActive] = 0
WHERE Id in (SELECT Id FROM #T)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TrippingTariffTransactionAuditTrail]
(LogDatetime, MasterlistId, ComputerName, TrippingTariffTransactionID, Activity)                       

SELECT 
GETDATE(), @MasterlistId, @ComputerName, Id, @Activity 
FROM #T

DROP TABLE #T
```

Comment: IMO,if #T will hold many records then EXISTS clause will work better than IN